# Re-render child component when back button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

Im wondering if there is any straightforward way to get a single child component to rerender when the back button is clicked. For example:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
   forceupdate > child-one
}

<parent>
  <child-one />
  <child-two />
</parent>
```

`componentWillReceiveProps` is hit whenever the back button is clicked.

Any ideas? I don't want to re-render the entire parent component.

Comment: The browser's back button? If you add routes, with `react-router` you can do this.

Comment: I've already got it configured with `react-router`, Im just wondering how to update a single component as mentioned above.

Comment: Then can you show more of your app? That wasn't at all clear from your question. And does it render the appropriate views given the route after the back button is pressed?

Answer (score -1):

If for some reason you want the children to re-render you could use key prop passed to them. This key prop which is used by React Reconciliation will just throw the old component and create a new one, thus re-render.

```
<parent>
  <child-one key={control} />
  <child-two />
</parent>
```

Sources: https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys